# How to include a DLL file and use it in C# with the "using" statement (and not installing/importing via VS)?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, dllimport

I'm trying to use a local DLL file in a .NET C# snippet that is used/called from within a PowerShell function.

The DLL file is the sensor library from [LibreHardwareMonitor](https://github.com/LibreHardwareMonitor/LibreHardwareMonitor), that is normally installed via their `nuget` [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LibreHardwareMonitorLib/). However, I don't have *nuget* and I don't want to install it either, since I think it should be possible to install this library manually.
(*What is nuget doing?*)

Here's my powershell code:

```
function print_cpu_temp {
    $ccode = @'
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
    // testing:
    //public static System.Reflection.Assembly UnsafeLoadFrom("C:\dev\LibreHardwareMonitorLib.dll");
    Assembly LibreHardwareMonitor;
    LibreHardwareMonitor = Assembly.LoadFrom("C:\dev\LibreHardwareMonitorLib.dll");
    
    using LibreHardwareMonitor.Hardware;

    namespace TheCpuTemp {
        public class MyCpuTemp {
            public class UpdateVisitor : IVisitor {
                public void VisitComputer(IComputer computer) {
                    computer.Traverse(this);
                }
                public void VisitHardware(IHardware hardware) {
                    hardware.Update();
                    foreach (IHardware subHardware in hardware.SubHardware) subHardware.Accept(this);
                }
                public void VisitSensor(ISensor sensor) { }
                public void VisitParameter(IParameter parameter) { }
            }

            public static void GetSystemInfo() {
                UpdateVisitor updateVisitor = new UpdateVisitor();
                Computer computer = new Computer();
                computer.Open();
                computer.CPUEnabled = true;
                computer.Accept(updateVisitor);
                
                for (int i = 0; i < computer.Hardware.Length; i++) {
                    if (computer.Hardware[i].HardwareType == HardwareType.CPU) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < computer.Hardware[i].Sensors.Length; j++) {
                            if (computer.Hardware[i].Sensors[j].SensorType == SensorType.Temperature)
                                Console.WriteLine(computer.Hardware[i].Sensors[j].Name + ":" + computer.Hardware[i].Sensors[j].Value.ToString() + "\r");
                        }
                    }
                }
                computer.Close();
            }

            public static void Main(string[] args) {
                while (true) {
                    GetSystemInfo();
                    //Task.Delay(500).Wait();   // wait 500 ms
                }
            }
        }
    }
'@

    Add-Type -TypeDefinition "$ccode"
    [MyCpuTemp]::GetSystemInfo()
}

print_cpu_temp
```

Q: **How can I load the DLL assembly and be able to use it within the C#**?
(I.e. In the same way as using `using xxx`.)

---

PS. I know you can use things like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);
```

But this is not practical in this case, as there are 100's of methods in that library.

---

**`UPDATE`**
This is obviously not the practical way to do this, unless you know exactly what you are doing, in which case this could potentially save you having to install the entire range of multi-gigabyte VS Code and C# compilers etc.

I tried another variaton on the above, that look like this:

```
    $another = @'
using System;
using System.Text;
using LibreHardwareMonitor;
using LibreHardwareMonitor.Hardware;
//using HidLibrary;

namespace TheCpuTemp {
    public class MyCpuTemp {

        public class UpdateVisitor : IVisitor {
            public void VisitComputer(IComputer computer) { computer.Traverse(this);    }
            public void VisitHardware(IHardware hardware) { hardware.Update(); foreach (IHardware subHardware in hardware.SubHardware) subHardware.Accept(this); }
            public void VisitSensor(ISensor sensor) { }
            public void VisitParameter(IParameter parameter) { }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args) {   
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            UpdateVisitor visitor= new UpdateVisitor();

            Computer computer = new Computer {
                IsCpuEnabled = true,
                IsGpuEnabled = true,
                IsMemoryEnabled = false,
                IsMotherboardEnabled = false,
                IsControllerEnabled = false,
                IsNetworkEnabled = false,
                IsStorageEnabled = false
            };

            computer.Open();
            computer.Accept(new UpdateVisitor());

            foreach (IHardware hardware in computer.Hardware) {
                Console.WriteLine("Hardware: {0}", hardware.Name);
                foreach (IHardware subhardware in hardware.SubHardware) {
                    Console.WriteLine("\tSubhardware: {0}", subhardware.Name);        
                    foreach (ISensor sensor in subhardware.Sensors) { 
                    Console.WriteLine("\t\tSensor: {0}, value: {1}", sensor.Name, sensor.Value); 
                    }
                }
                foreach (ISensor sensor in hardware.Sensors) { 
                    Console.WriteLine("\tSensor: {0}, value: {1}", sensor.Name, sensor.Value);
                }
            }
            computer.Close();
        }
    }
}
'@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition "$another" -ReferencedAssemblies "C:\dev\LibreHardwareMonitorLib.dll", "System.dll", "System.Management.Automation.dll" -PassThru

[MyCpuTemp]::Main()
```

But that also failed...

Comment: referencing a .NET assembly and `DllImport` to access native DLLs are two entirely different things.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `-ReferencedAssemblies` parameter of PowerShell's  [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Add-Type) cmdlet in your call.

Comment: Yes, I tried this, but then it fails by not being able to find "linq" and then if I comment that out, it says I need the `mscore` assembly and then trying various other reductions, I also complains that `Console.WriteLine()` is not recognized. I don't know what any of these things are, so I am thinking this is getting complicated.